# WSO2 Identity Server - User disabling does not work until the server is restarted

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using the WSO2 Identity Server version 5.3.0. I'm also using WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0.
I created 2 APIs, one which disables the user which by calling the admin service and also an API to enable the user as well. I also created an API to check the user status(disabled/enabled) which checks whether the relevant user is enabled or disabled once the username is entered.

The whole process works fine for a couple of rounds.

disable a user -> check the status(user gets displayed as disabled) -> enable the same user -> check the status(user gets displayed as enabled)

However, if the same user is disabled from a remote computer, the status wrongly gets displayed as enabled and also the user does not get disabled as well. But after I **restart** the Identity Server, the status gets displayed correctly as disabled and the user is also seen as disabled from the previous API call.

Has this issue got something to do with the cache in Identity Server?

Any suggestive approach to solve this issue is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems you have more than one node of Identity Server in your deployment. If so, you have to enable clustering in order for the caches to be synced. Otherwise the cache update in node 1 won't be reflected in the node 2 until the cache expiry time reaches (default 15 minutes) or a restart.

[Enabling clustering for US 5.3.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1#SettingUpDeploymentPattern1-ClusteringIdentityServerforhighavailability)